# Margin between frame title block and frame edge

Tags: beamer, frame-title

How can I remove the margin showed in figure below? There is no any definition for headline (I define only footline). 
All defined options for frame title is:

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size={\large}}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size={\footnotesize}}
```

[image: Problem]

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminB}{argmax} 
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10pt, text margin right=5pt} 

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size={\large}}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size={\footnotesize}}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\small}
%spacing between lines
\usepackage{setspace}

%remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
%new colors
\definecolor{back}{rgb}{0.98, 0.98,0.98 }
\definecolor{2green}{rgb}{0, 0.16, 0.26}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\definecolor{green-for-code}{rgb}{0, 0.6, 0}
\usepackage{multirow}



%defining colors of elements
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=2green}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=2green}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=2green}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=2green}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=2green}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=2green}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=2green}
\setbeamercolor{description item}{fg=2green}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg = white, bg = 2green!60}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg = black, bg = anti-flashwhite}
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=2green}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


%templates for elements
\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem        \hfill}
\setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\textbf{\theenumi}.}


%defining the footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\paperwidth,ht=10ex,dp=1ex,right]    {subsection in head/foot}%
        \color{2green}{\insertsection} \hspace*{0ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}%
\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.1\paperwidth,ht=10ex,dp=1ex,right]    {subsection in head/foot}%
        \color{2green}{\insertframenumber{}} / \inserttotalframenumber    \hspace*{5ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}%
\vskip0pt%
}

   \title{Title}
\subtitle{subTitle}
\author{}

\date{}




\begin{document}
%---------------------------% 

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
}


\section{Sectio}
\subsection{subsection}

%---------------------------% 
\begin{frame}[fragile]{\insertsubsection}
\begin{block}{}
Text
\end{block}
\begin{itemize}
    \item item1
    \item item1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%---------------------------%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I've added the MWE

Comment: Would it be possible to reduce the code the minimum necessary to reproduce the error. Especially can you make an example which does not need special fonts to compile?

Comment: Furthermore there is a syntax error in `\author{XXX}{XXX}}`. And you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer.

Comment: I also get the error `Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Cyrill(polyglossia) Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily. \select@language {russian}`

Comment: I've updated MWE

Comment: Funnily enough this space at the left margin is caused by changing the right margin

Comment: It's very strange, because before updating MikTeX this margin was also 10pt, but everything was good. Anyway, thank you very much/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the unit `pt` is not a fixed length, but depends on the current font size. This means that if the frametitle takes the margin into account, this margin has another size than when the position of the frametitle on the frame is calculated.

To circumvent this problem, use a fixed unit to define your margin, e.g. `cm`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.3cm, text margin right=0.3cm} 
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]